# How to install dkim-filter by apt-get?

Tags: installation, apt, package-management

In tutorial, DKIM is installed by

```
sudo apt-get install dkim-filter
```

I wonder why on my Ubuntu 10.10, I am unable to do this as I receive error of

```
E: Unable to locate package dkim-filter
```

How can I install DKIM by `apt-get`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe because it is not there anymore in [10.10](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package_metas?exact_match=1&q=dkim-filter):

```
Package "dkim-filter"


WARNING: the "dkim-filter" package was deleted from this repository


Name:   dkim-filter

Description:    
DomainKeys Identified Mail (DKIM) Milter implementation 
Implements a Sendmail Mail Filter (Milter) for the DomainKeys 
Identified Mail (DKIM) standard. DKIM provides a way for senders to 
confirm their identity when sending email by adding a cryptographic 
signature to the headers of the message.

The dkim-milter implements both signing and verification.

Latest version: *DELETED*
Release:    maverick (10.10)
Level:  base
Repository: universe
Head package:   dkim-milter
```

However I've found [this](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/maverick/+package/dkim-filter) googling a little bit. Just download the `.deb` file an install it.

Comment: It's strange that such a popular package is absent in ubuntu 10.10. Thanks for making me sure that it's not the problem of my system :)

Comment: No problem. I'm glad it helped :)